# Do I need ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission if I have INTERNET one

Tags: android

I had an INTERNET permission in my app. But now I want to add google analytics in my app. And it says it need a CHECK_INTERNET_SATE. Do I have to add it? If so, it looks very strange - app, which can access internet can't read it's state. I don't think it's normal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a basic difference between these 2 permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The above permission **Allows applications to open network sockets**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Where as above `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission  **Allows applications to access information about networks.**

**Example:**

If you want to load a URL in a `WebView`, you only need `android.permission.INTERNET` permission.

If there is a situation where you have to download some data from a server, you need to check internet connection availability before downloading. Otherwise app may crash if there is no connectivity.Like following ways, you can check internet connectivity,

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the above snippet, you are fetching information about the network so here you have to take  `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

> And it says it need a CHECK_INTERNET_SATE. Do I have to add it?

**Google Analytics SDK** checks network availability before sending information to the server so you need that permission too.

Hope it clears your doubt.

reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642087/1665507